# ConnBean object in sshexec not getting cleared or reset

Tags: netbeans, ssh, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Netbeans 8.1 and JavaFX scene builder to make App. Where I need to perform a ssh connection test on a button click for that I have used sshexec jar from https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/ here, I tried it in my application see below code snippet

```
     SSHExec ssh = null;

     int val = 0;
     String getURLFromUI=txtServerUrl.getText().trim();
     String getUsernameFromUI=txtUserName.getText().trim();
     String getPasswordFromUI=pwdPassword.getText().trim();

        System.out.println("URL : " +getURLFromUI);
            System.out.println("User : " +getUsernameFromUI);
            System.out.println("Pass : " +getPasswordFromUI);
    try {

       ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(getURLFromUI, getUsernameFromUI,getPasswordFromUI);
        ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);  

        boolean connected = ssh.connect();
        if(connected){

            val++;
            showBuildServerStatus.setText("Connection Done!!!!!!" +val);
        }else{
            val++;
            showBuildServerStatus.setText("Connection Failed!!!!!!"+val);
        }
   // ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb1);   
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
            {

                ssh.disconnect();   

               }
```

When I run my application, found below issues:

1. If I do 3-4 clicks(without restarting the application) with valid/invalid parameters, the ConnBean object does not get reset.

Expected: In every click values should get updated.

E.g. If user provides `1.1.1.1` at the very first time below line printed in console :

```
Trying to connect root@1.1.1.1
```

In secoond try user provides `2.2.2.2` below line printed on console:

```
Trying to connect root@1.1.1.1
```

So, my concern is :

1. Is my code right?am I missing something important?
2. In every click connection should be made on given values.

P.S. : In system.print shows the correct values (as per user input) but when ssh.connect(); method called from SSHEXEC api it shows the first passed value.

Please let me know if question is unclear.

**UPDATE 1:**

By using [https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/issues/detail?id=8](http://this%20patch) this patch above problem is fixed. But one more thing I am concern is

after successfully executing the script it shows `Now wait 5 seconds to begin next task ...` and the script gets executed again. See below snippet:

```
CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("/usr/checkoutcode.sh");
Result rs = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
```

Anybody have any idea why this crap is happening??

Comment: Apologies for the bad English, please feel free to update.

Comment: There is a issue regarding your problem. You could find a solution [here](https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/issues/detail?id=8)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Inge .. It seems very useful.

Comment: It is working now. One more thing that is really frustrating, after successfully executing the script it shows `Now wait 5 seconds to begin next task ...` and again executes. The problem is one task getting executed two times. any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to set SSHExec.setOption(IOptionName.INTEVAL_TIME_BETWEEN_TASKS, 5000l);? Set its value to 50 but don't forget the I at the end. You can find this method in section 4.5 of the above link.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem take a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/issues/detail?id=8) issue and the solution mentioned in there

Second problem could be solved by setting 
`SSHExec.setOption(IOptionName.INTEVAL_TIME_BETWEEN_TASKS, 5000l);`

to

`SSHExec.setOption(IOptionName.INTEVAL_TIME_BETWEEN_TASKS, 50l);`

You can find this method in section 4.5 of the above link.